# Elliptical distribution - properties

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

An $n$-dimensional random vector $X=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ follows an elliptical distribution with mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and positive definite covariance matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ if 
$$Z \stackrel{d}{=}\mu + \xi AU,$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfies $A A^\top= \Sigma$, $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly distributed on $\mathbb{S}_{n-1}$ and $\xi$ an unspecified random variable, independent of $U$ and $\mathbf{E}(\xi^2)=n$.

Now according to http://www.leg.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/wiki:internas:biblioteca:applied_multivariate_statistics.pdf, page 170 we have:

1. Any linear combination of elliptically distributed variables are elliptical.
2. Marginal distributions of elliptically distributed variables are elliptical.
3. The characteristic function $\phi(t)=\mathbf{E}(e^{it^\top X})$ of $X$ is of the form: 
   $$\phi(t)=e^{it^\top \mu}\psi(t^\top \Sigma t)$$

Now first the understanding:

1. In number 1 is written, "elliptical distributed variable", not vector, so does this mean, that for x,y being elliptical distributed,  $\lambda x+\mu y$ for constants $\lambda$, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ is only elliptical distributed, if $x$ and $y$ are both 1-dimenisonal distributed but it is not true for the general case, that $x$ and $y$ are $n$-dimensional distributed? Is there any regulations about that $x$ and $y$ must be independent or identically distributed?(identically meaning elliptically distributed with the same parameters)
2. states that for $X=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ $x_i$ is 1-dimensional elliptical distributed for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, right?

Also I am looking for ideas how to prove the three statements... Is there anyone able to give me an idea on how to start a proof?

Comment: For 1, a random variable can still be a vector, so it's just saying that $\sum_{k= 1}^{n} \alpha_k \boldsymbol{X}_k$ is elliptical if the $\boldsymbol{X}_k$ are elliptical -- obviously it's sufficient to show it just for $n = 2$. For 2, yes. For proofs I expect you can use 3 to prove 1 fairly easily, so maybe start with 3 and go from there.

Comment: Hello Will... So 1. denotes the general $n$-dimensional case? Do I need independence or identically distributed or is it true without additional assumptions regarding that?

Comment: I believe so, yes. I don't think you need an i.i.d assumption, but I'm not 100% sure. You will need independence to use 3 to imply 1, though. I'm fairly sure elliptical distributions are a subfamily of the stable distributions, so you wouldn't need i.i.d :) Elliptical dist'ns are basically generalisations of MV-normal, so the proofs for the normal case should give you some pointers, too.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318242/is-this-calculation-regarding-the-characteristic-function-correct Check my question here... Is the calculation correct? How can I prove 2?

Comment: For 1, I also think that 1-dimensional $x$ and $y$ would not make sense, because you need minimum 2-d in order to define a nontrivial case of different variances and/or correlation to get ellipticity for each r.v.

Comment: For 2, I think you could start by first showing, via substitution, that any linear transformation ${\bf B}^{\rm T} \cdot {\bf z}$ of ${\bf z}$ (= your $Z$) gives $\phi({\bf t}) = \exp(i{\bf t}^{\rm T} {\bf B}^{\rm T} \cdot {\bf z}) \psi({\bf t}^{\rm T} \cdot ( {\bf B}^{\rm T} \cdot {\bf \Sigma} \cdot {\bf B} ) \cdot {\bf t})$, if I'm not mistaken. If you then chose ${\bf B}^{\rm T}$ to be a null matrix except for one(s) on suitable places on its diagonal -- which are chosen to correspond to pick out the marginal variables that you want -- you still have an elliptic marginal.  Would that work?

Comment: I tried and it works - thanks a lot.. :-)