# Is my calculation correct?(calculating characteristic function of elliptical distributed r.v., convolution and marginal distribution)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

This is a follow-up of this question: : 
[Compute $\phi_X(t)=E(e^{it^\top X})$ if $X\stackrel{d}{=}\mu + \xi AU$ with $AA^\top=\Sigma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318242/compute-phi-xt-eeit-top-x-if-x-stackreld-mu-xi-au-with-aa)

Let $X\stackrel{d}{=}\mu + \xi AU$ be an elliptical distributed random vector, with $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ and $U\in \mathbb{R^n}$ independent, $\mu$ an $n$-dimensional vector; A a $n \times n$ matrix with $A A^T=\Sigma$;

Then the following holds:

1. The characteristic function $\phi(t)=\mathbf{E}(e^{it^\top X})$ of $X$ is of the form: 
   $$\phi_X(t)=e^{it^\top \mu}\psi(t^\top \Sigma t)$$
2. Any linear combination of elliptically distributed vectors is elliptical.
3. Marginal distributions of elliptically distributed vectors are elliptical.

Proof:
1. For the characteristic function of $X$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
   \phi_X(t) &=& \mathbb{E}\left( \exp(i t^\top(\mu + \xi AU) \right) =\exp(i t^\top \mu)  \mathbb{E}\left(\exp(i t^\top\xi AU)\right)=\exp(i t^\top \mu)\mathbb{E}\left( \mathbb{E}\left( \exp(i t^\top\xi AU) | \xi \right) \right) \\
  &=& \exp(i t^\top \mu) \mathbb{E}\left( \phi_{U}\left(A^\top \xi t \right) \right)=\exp(i t^\top \mu) \mathbb{E}\left( \psi_{U}\left(t^\top \xi A A^\top \xi t  \right) \right) \\ 
 &=& \exp(i t^\top \mu) \mathbb{E}\left( \psi_{U}\left(\xi^2 t^\top \Sigma t \right) \right),
\end{eqnarray*}
where we used the law of total expectation and $\phi_U(t)=\psi(t^Tt)$. Now defining $\psi(s)=\mathbb{E}\left( \psi_{U}\left(\xi^2 s \right) \right)$, we get the desired result. \
In fact it is also possible to prove the other direction. A random variable is elliptically distributed if and only if the characteristic function is of the form $\phi_X(t)=e^{it^\top \mu}\psi(t^\top \Sigma t)$. For a proof, see [Frahm, 2004].

2. We only prove it for $X$, $Y$ being independent. \
   Let $X$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two elliptically distributed vectors, independent of each other. Since $\phi_{cX}(t)=\exp(i t^\top c \mu)  \mathbb{E}\left(\exp(i t^\top c \xi AU)\right)=\exp(i t^\top c \mu)\psi(t^\top c \Sigma c t)=\exp(i t^\top c \mu)\psi(c^2 t^\top \Sigma t)$,  $\psi$ is also only dependent on $t^\top \Sigma t$ and for this reason with the comment in (1), $cX$ and $bY$ are also elliptical $\forall b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

We then have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
   \phi_{aX+bY}(t) &=& \phi_{aX}(t) \cdot \phi_{bY}(t)=\exp(i t^\top (\mu_1+\mu_2))\psi_{cX}(t^\top \Sigma t)\psi_{bY}(t^\top \Sigma t),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ describes the mean of $cX$, respectively $bY$ and  $\psi_{cX}$ respectively $\psi_{bY}$ describes the functions for describing the characteristic function of $cX$ and $bY$. \
Defining $\psi(.)=\psi_{cX}(.)\psi_{bY}(.)$ yields the desired result.

3. We prove that $BX$ is elliptical for all matrices $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. We have: 
   \begin{eqnarray*}
      \phi_{BX}(t) &=& \mathbb{E}\left( \exp(i t^\top BX \right)=\phi_{X}(B^\top t) =\exp(i t^\top B \mu)\psi_X(t^\top B \Sigma B^\top t).
   \end{eqnarray*}

So first of all: Is everything I wrote so far correct? But now with 3. I don't know how to continue;

Saying that the characteristic function consists of a function $\psi$, dependent only on $t^T \Sigma t$ means that the function $\psi$ is only dependent on the 1-dimensional product of $t^T \Sigma t$, which is clearly not given with $t^\top B \Sigma B^\top t$;

I got the hint to prove it like that on this page but it seems to not work somehow - or am I doing a mistake?

I'm very glad about some help;

The advices I got are can also be found here: 
[Compute $\phi_X(t)=E(e^{it^\top X})$ if $X\stackrel{d}{=}\mu + \xi AU$ with $AA^\top=\Sigma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318242/compute-phi-xt-eeit-top-x-if-x-stackreld-mu-xi-au-with-aa)

Comment: Providing a link to your previous question, whose comments this one is benefitting from, is not an option because?

Comment: Because I was afraid the questions could get closed although the first question is only related to the first thing I wanted to prove(which should be alright by now) Sorry; Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318242/compute-phi-xt-eeit-top-x-if-x-stackreld-mu-xi-au-with-aa

Comment: IOW, you are trying to play clever with the rules of the site? Anyway, add the link to the body of your question.

Comment: Well I'm working on a paper and try to use the ideas I get from this page but also get stuck from time to time; If this is the old question asked again or a new question is probably a matter of perspective... But if you can help me, you'd make me really really happy..

Comment: Oh I also still don't know if the sum of dependent elliptical distributed random vectors of the same dimension are really elliptical distributed - if you know that, you could help a lot as well...

Comment: I don't understand your problem with 3)? The $t$ is not the same in both functions. It's $n$-dimensional in $\varphi_X(t)$ and $m$-dimensional in $\varphi_{BX}(t)$. $BX$ is elliptical with 'mean' parameter $B\mu$ and 'covariance matrix' $B \Sigma B^\top$.

Comment: What I mean to say is that your $t$ in 3) is $m$-dimensional.